# Can we shorten the jquery code I have written in my js?

Tags: jquery

I am a beginner in jquery. I have created a small jquery thianimate function.

But I feel my jquery code is too long.

Please help me out to shorten the code. I have written so many lines to keep the animation effect.

```js
bindEvents();

function bindEvents(){
oldClickedNumber=0;
$('.dice').hide();

 $('.numbers').on('click', function() {
 clickedNumber=$(this).text();
 
  if (clickedNumber==1){
   $('#dice_1').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).show();
   if (oldClickedNumber==2){ 
    $('#dice_1').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).show();
    $('#dice_2').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).show();
    $('#dice_3').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).hide();
    $('#dice_4').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).hide();
    $('#dice_5').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).hide();
    $('#dice_6').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).hide();
   } else if (oldClickedNumber==3){
    $('#dice_3').hide().animate({'top': '0', left: '0' });
    $('#dice_1').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).show();
    $('#dice_2').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).show();
    
   } else if (oldClickedNumber==4){ 
    $('#dice_1').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).show();
    $('#dice_2').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).show();
    $('#dice_3').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).show();
    $('#dice_4').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).show();
   } else if (oldClickedNumber==5){ 
    $('#dice_1').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).show();
    $('#dice_2').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).show();
    $('#dice_3').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).show();
    $('#dice_4').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).show();
    $('#dice_5').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).show();
   } else if (oldClickedNumber==6){ 
    $('#dice_1').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).show();
    $('#dice_2').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).show();
    $('#dice_3').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).show();
    $('#dice_4').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).show();
    $('#dice_5').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).show();
    $('#dice_6').animate({'top': '0', left: '0' }).show();
   }
   oldClickedNumber=clickedNumber;
  } else  if (clickedNumber==2){
   //$('.dice').hide();
   $('#dice_1').show().animate({'top': '-40', left: '40' });
   $('#dice_2').show().animate({'top': '40', left: '-40' });
   $('#dice_3').hide().animate({'top': '0', left: '0' });
   $('#dice_4').hide().animate({'top': '0', left: '0' });
   $('#dice_5').hide().animate({'top': '0', left: '0' });
   $('#dice_6').hide().animate({'top': '0', left: '0' });
   oldClickedNumber=clickedNumber;
  } else  if (clickedNumber==3){
   //$('.dice').hide();
   $('#dice_1').show().animate({'top': '-50', left: '50' });
   $('#dice_2').show().animate({'top': '50', left: '-50' });
   $('#dice_3').show().animate({'top': '0', left: '0' });
   $('#dice_4').show().animate({'top': '0', left: '0' });
   $('#dice_5').show().animate({'top': '0', left: '0' });
   $('#dice_6').show().animate({'top': '0', left: '0' });
   oldClickedNumber=clickedNumber;
  } else  if (clickedNumber==4){
   //$('.dice').hide();
   $('#dice_1').show().animate({'top': '-40', left: '40' });
   $('#dice_2').show().animate({'top': '40', left: '-40' });
   $('#dice_3').show().animate({'top': '-40', left: '-40' });
   $('#dice_4').show().animate({'top': '40', left: '40' });
   $('#dice_5').hide().animate({'top': '0', left: '0' });
   $('#dice_6').hide().animate({'top': '0', left: '0' });
   oldClickedNumber=clickedNumber;
  } else  if (clickedNumber==5){
   //$('.dice').hide();
   $('#dice_1').show().animate({'top': '-50', left: '50' });
   $('#dice_2').show().animate({'top': '50', left: '-50' });
   $('#dice_3').show().animate({'top': '-50', left: '-50' });
   $('#dice_4').show().animate({'top': '50', left: '50' });
   $('#dice_5').show().animate({'top': '0', left: '0' });
   $('#dice_6').show().animate({'top': '0', left: '0' });
   oldClickedNumber=clickedNumber;
  } else  if (clickedNumber==6){
   //$('.dice').hide();
   $('#dice_1').show().animate({'top': '-50', left: '50' });
   $('#dice_2').show().animate({'top': '50', left: '-50' });
   $('#dice_3').show().animate({'top': '-50', left: '-50' });
   $('#dice_4').show().animate({'top': '50', left: '50' });
   $('#dice_5').show().animate({'top': '50', left: '0' });
   $('#dice_6').show().animate({'top': '-50', left: '0' });
   oldClickedNumber=clickedNumber;
  }
 });

};
```

```css
.mainContainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #8BC34A;
}

.question {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.stage {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

.numButtons {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.buttonsResult {
  background: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.dice {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-top: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 85px;
}

.numbers {
  color: white;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 25px;
  /* width: 88px; */
  /* height: 55px; */
  float: left;
  padding-right: 4px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainContainer">
    <div class="question">Click the numbers on left to see the same number of DOTs on right.
    </div>
    <div class="stage">
      <div class="numButtons">
        <div class="numbers" id="one">1</div>
        <div class="numbers" id="two">2</div>
        <div class="numbers" id="three">3</div>
        <div class="numbers" id="four">4</div>
        <div class="numbers" id="five">5</div>
        <div class="numbers" id="six">6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="buttonsResult">
        <div class="dice" id="dice_1"></div>
        <div class="dice" id="dice_2"></div>
        <div class="dice" id="dice_3"></div>
        <div class="dice" id="dice_4"></div>
        <div class="dice" id="dice_5"></div>
        <div class="dice" id="dice_6"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chetanpandey/pbmr1aty/1/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not intended for full code review. (See the other Stack Exchange site [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) which is designed for this purpose.)

Comment: I think SO wants you to show some actual code.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would create a list of 6 objects acting as definitions of each face of the die. Every such object would have a list of 6 objects representing states of the dots for the face - if it's visible and its position if it is:

```
faces = [[
  // One - all visible at the same position for the animation of all dots converging to one
  { visible: true, x: 0, y: 0 },
  { visible: true, x: 0, y: 0 },
  { visible: true, x: 0, y: 0 },
  { visible: true, x: 0, y: 0 },
  { visible: true, x: 0, y: 0 },
  { visible: true, x: 0, y: 0 }
], [
  // Two
  { visible: true, x: -40, y: -40 },
  { visible: true, x: 40, y: 40 },
  { visible: false },
  { visible: false },
  { visible: false },
  { visible: false }
], ....]
```

The click event would then read the definition of the appropriate face, iterate over the dot elements and then hide or show each of them, animating them to the appropriate positions.